# Heroku: running pg_restore from a local file returns errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to load test db from a file store locally (db.sql), using

```
heroku run pg_restore -d foo db.sql
```

the error message I am getting says:

```
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package.
```

I tried to do `sudo apt-get postgresql-client-9.4.1`, and get:

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

and without `sudo`, I get:

```
E: Invalid operation postgresql-client-9.4.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a locally-installed `pg_restore` to restore your data into the Heroku-hosted database.

I usually run something like this:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h [host address] -p [port] -U [username] -d [name] [file path]
```

More info here:
[PostgreSQL Backup and Restore Commands](http://www.liveeditorcms.com/gc/playbook/postgresql-backup-restore/)

Comment: what about the errors that throws with constraints?.......The database imports but with relation errors and contraints errors...do I have to disable contrainsts to use this command?